# "jhipster aws" Error: not authorized to perform: iam:GetInstanceProfile on resource: instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

Tags: jhipster

I run `jhipster aws` in my project folder and I answer the prompts.

```
C:\AWSworkspace\jhaws>jhipster aws  
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules  
INFO! Executing jhipster:aws  
INFO! Options: from-cli: true  
? Application name: jhaws   
? Environment name: jhaws-env  
? Name of S3 bucket: jhaws  
? Database name: jhaws  
? Database username: jhawsadmin  
? Database password: [hidden]  
? On which EC2 instance type do you want to deploy? t2.micro  
? On which RDS instance class do you want to deploy? db.t2.micro  
? On which region do you want to deploy? us-east-1  
Building application
```

This creates the S3 bucket, uploads the jar, creates the database, and brings up the database, but when it gets to `Verifying ElasticBeanstalk Roles` I get the message:

```
Verifying ElasticBeanstalk Roles  
Error: User: arn:aws:iam::173874802293:user/progaccess is not authorized to perform: iam:GetInstanceProfile on resource: instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role  
    at Environment.error (C:\AWSworkspace\jhaws\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:176:40)  
    at module.exports.error (C:\AWSworkspace\jhaws\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:1448:18)  
    at iam.verifyRoles.err (C:\AWSworkspace\jhaws\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\index.js:228:30)  
    at hasInstanceRole.then.then.then.then.then.then.catch.err (C:\AWSworkspace\jhaws\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\lib\iam.js:214:13)  
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The user, `progaccess`, gets its permissions from the `progaccess` group. These are the permissions:

```
AWSCodeCommitFullAccess  
IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials  
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier  
AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess  
AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker  
AmazonRDSDataFullAccess  
AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
```

I have added the permissions that are listed for the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` role so I don't know what permissions I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add permission IAM : GetInstanceProfile for the user. Documented AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy is not enough

Comment: Would you happen to know the name of the policy that has that capability?  If I could add that policy, then it should work.  Thanks.

Comment: I created a new policy including only that specific permission

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the policy IAMReadOnlyAccess to the group because it contains the permission **IAM : GetInstanceProfile**.